# How to access variables within MovieClip (AS3)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm new in AS3 and I wanna ask how to access variables inside MovieClips by its name.

in AS2 usually, I use its instance name followed by `.(name of variable)`

for example... 
I have a variable named baru inside a MovieClip named `my_mc`.
usually I use `my_mc.baru` to reveal the value of the variable.

Now, i want to know how to do it in AS3

Thank you.

Comment: MovieClipName.variableName

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In AS3 there's a few separate but related things you need to be aware of:

- All display objects (including `MovieClip`) can have a [`name`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#name) property.

  ```
  var mc:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
  mc.name = "myMC";
  myContainer.addChild(mc);
  ```
- You can find a child by its `name` using [`getChildByName()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#getChildByName()) on its parent.

  ```
  var myMC:MovieClip = myContainer.getChildByName("myMC");
  ```
- `MoveClip` instances can have [dynamic properties](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f89.html) that point to children (or anything at all).

  ```
  myContainer.myMC = myMC;
  ```

  (Note that other display object types, such as `Sprite`, do *not* allow dynamic properties. Instead you need to create a custom class with class properties.)
- When you create a display object in code (as shown above), neither the `name` or a property on the parent will be automatically created. You can do it manually as shown above.
- When you place a symbol instance in the authoring tool and give it an "instance name", *both* the `name` *and* a property on the parent symbol will be assigned by that "instance name". In this case you are not allowed to change the `name` in code.
- **Note that in AS2 using `createEmptyMovieClip` or `attachMovie` would assign the `_name` and create a property on the parent, but there's no AS3 equivalent to these functions.** This is where a lot of confusion can come in.

So as you can see the way this works is really not different than AS2, except that AS2 had functions that did several things for you (create and add the MovieClip, set the `name` and add a property on the parent). The problem with AS2 was that you couldn't re-parent an object after it was created, which was a big limitation. In AS3 you can freely move things around.

Answer (score -1):

If you just like to write code inside the MovieClip but not a *.as,you have to add a TextField in the MovieClip by hand,set it's type to Dynamic,then type the variable string in it,then get it use: MovieClip.TextField.text and don't forget: TextField.alpha=0.

It is not a wise way.